# How can I get Dutch Citizenship?

Tags: citizenship

My great grandfather was a Dutch citizen however, when he moved to New Zealand, it was renounced. I am currently living in Australia. Is there any way I would be able to acquire Dutch Citizenship? I am also only 16 if that helps.

Comment: Probably not.  You would have to be able to establish an unbroken line of Dutch nationality from your great grandfather to you.  If your great grandfather lost Dutch nationality after his child who is your grandmother or grandfather reached the age of majority (probably 21 at the time), then your grandmother or grandfather was Dutch and your father or mother might have been Dutch.  And so on...  So it depends a lot on the timing of all of these events.

Comment: You can [edit]() the question to add the dates, if you know them.  There are also circumstances in which acquisition of another nationality does not cause loss of Dutch nationality, but these are not common in practice.